# Why don't we merge edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

If a post is edited by multiple users at the same time, why can't we merge them?

Some might say that this is dangerous as the new answer might not make sense. I do not think this would commonly be a problem. Keep in mind that merging is used with source code successfully, which is much more sensitive to changes.

Comment: Keeping in mind that one downside is that it's more difficult to determine ownership of edits, what would you say are the upsides to this approach?

Comment: Because they can't be merged. If there's substantial conflicts, it would be difficult to say which one to implement. What if one of them is a bad edit? Regardless, does this matter?

Answer (score 2):

When do multiple users edit posts *at the same time*? There may be a clash every now and again, but there's no reason why someone effected by this can't edit the post after the first edit.

2k+ users would have their changes made immediately (or can go and review any suggested edit made and improve or reject and edit that), so this only affects <2k users who want to make an edit whilst another <2k user is having their suggested edit reviewed. It doesn't happen that often I would suspect. Far too much of an edge case for me.